# Prove by induction $\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\tfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)=\tfrac{n+2}{2n+2}$

Tags: summation, induction

How to prove this by induction?
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\tfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)=\tfrac{n+2}{2n+2}$$

Comment: Kindly add what you've tried. Cause, we don't know who really has doubt and who wants us to solve their online exam paper.

Comment: Are you struggling with the base step, the inductive step or both?

Comment: @Ak Okay I will add my attempt in a few minutes, sorry about it

Comment: Anyway, this formula looks very wrong. The left-hand side is asymptotic to $n$, the right-hand side to $\tfrac12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the following:

Base case: $k=1$

We have: $1-\frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{1+2}{2+2}=\frac{3}{4}$ which is correct.

Assuming this is true for $n$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\tfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)=\tfrac{n+2}{2n+2}$ is true, we need to show it is true for $n+1$ such that  $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(1-\tfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)=\tfrac{n+3}{2n+4}$

We have $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(1-\tfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-\tfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)+ 1-\tfrac{1}{(n+2)^2}=\tfrac{n+2}{2n+2}+1-\tfrac{1}{(n+2)^2}\neq \tfrac{n+3}{2n+4}$

Which means your preposition is wrong and this can't be proven.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem should be a product on the left side:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)=\dfrac{n+2}{2n+2}
$$
rather than summation.

Now let's begin.
For $n=1$, it is obviously true.

Assume it is true for $n=p$. That is, $\displaystyle \prod _{k=1}^p \left(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right) = \frac{p+2}{2 p+2}$ is already true. Now let's check $p+1$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\quad\prod_{k=1}^{p+1}{\left( 1-\frac{1}{\left( k+1 \right) ^2} \right)}
\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^p{\left( 1-\frac{1}{\left( k+1 \right) ^2} \right)}\times \frac{p^2+4p+3}{\left( p+2 \right) ^2}
\\
&=\frac{p+2}{2p+2}\times \frac{p^2+4p+3}{\left( p+2 \right) ^2}
\\
&=\frac{p+2}{2\left( p+1 \right)}\times \frac{\left( 1+p \right) \left( 3+p \right)}{\left( p+2 \right) ^2}
\\
&=\frac{p+3}{2p+4}
\\
&=\frac{\left( p+1 \right) +2}{2\left( p+1 \right) +2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus we finished the proof.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to leave a comment?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, I don't know who also downvoted my question!!

Comment: I upvoted your answer, thanks

Comment: This makes way more sense because in the limit, the left side diverges whereas the right side converges. Great catch.

Comment: @FFjet I've noticed quite a few valid answers to poor quality questions, such as PSQs (Problem Statement Questions), being down voted. Since your answer looks correct, the down vote may be due to you answering a PSQ. Also, I agree with Cameron Williams that noticing the problem should be using a product instead of a sum is a "great catch".